# having access to python-glpk internal functions

Tags: python, optimization, glpk

I am working on an optimization problem using Python-glpk (I need to have my code in python and have to use open source solver like glpk).
In this Python-glpk package, you can have your problem in 2 methods:

1- Read it from .lp or .mps etc files using for example "problem = glpk("route/to/.lp file/test_file.lp") " and then solve it using functions like:
- problem.update()
- proble.solve()

2 - Build and model your problem yourself starting with "problem = glp_create_prob() " and then use other functions to add variables and coefficients  and constraint and etc, and then solve it using functions like:
- glp_set_obj_coef(problem , int j, double coef)
- glp_get_obj_coef(problem , int j)

My problem is that I need to read the problem from .lp or .mps file and optimize it and at the same time I need to have access to the elements of the problem because I need to change them and optimize it again.
But I can not do that here(or at least I don't know how to do that) because when you build a problem in the method 1 then you don't have access to element like method 2.

I really appreciate your help.